# Unity3D Rigidbody AddForce with a vector and time

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game pretty much like bowling in Unity3D.

I already calculate the vector the user wants to apply to the "ball" and the time that vector takes to be made (to calculate his force). I mean, if we throw a bowling ball slowly the ball will move slow but if we throw it fast the ball will move faster.

And how can i apply the force having in consideration the vector and the time? So it's similar to reality, just as the bowling ball after some time it stops..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to apply *constant* force to the ball? You could track the player's input during the throw and calculate from that how much force the ball will be given. Then just add one *impulse* of force to the direction you already have.

Comment: That's what I'm doing atm:
rigidbody.AddForce(finalVetor*totalTime, ForceMode.Impulse);
And the force applied is good but the ball never stops it justs bounce with another objetcs gaining more velocity and i want to stop it after some time.